# Rapidminer Studio 6 - Loop operator

Tags: loops, rapidminer

Is there a way to iterates in steps of more than one on a Loop operator in Rapidminer 6? I'm abel to set number of iterations and the first value but not the step lenght (for saying so). Something like `for(i=0;i<N;i=i+5)`, so in each iteration `"i"` (the macro name) will be `0-5-10-15...` Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the loop, use the `Generate Macro` operator. My suggestion is to create a new macro based on the macro for the loop. So if the loop macro is called `iteration` you would set the `functions expression` for the `Generate Macro` to `%{iteration}*5` and the `macroname` to `mymacro`.